# Infinite sum of upper semicontinuous functions is NOT upper semicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis

This is from Papa Rudin Exercise 2.1 (c). If $f_n$ is a sequence of nonnegative upper semicontinuous functions, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ is upper semicontinuous. This is false; one counterexample that I found online is the sequence $f_n = \chi_{\left[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right]}$

The solution claims that $\sum_1 ^\infty f_n = \chi (0,1]$, which I doubt. Say $x = 1/2$, then $\chi [1/2, 1] + \chi [1/3, 1/2]$ is not a characteristic function.

Am I correct in my reasoning? What counterexample can I give?

Comment: I don't remember the notation for Papa Rudin, but could it be that they mean the $0$-$\infty$ indicator function? It appears that the sum identity would hold in this case. ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(convex_analysis)

Comment: Do you mean the notation of characteristic function?

Comment: Does the fact that $f(x) := \sum_1^\infty f_n(x) = 2$ for some $x$ change the fact that $f$ is not upper semicontinuous?

Comment: But then you have to show why the f is not usc.

Comment: I don't see how that would change the proof $f$ is not usc